# how to do it in vanilla js?

Tags: javascript, jquery

please help me write this in vanilla js. Mouseenter scares me. example https://jsfiddle.net/c01ot73d/5/

```
$('a.zag').on( "mouseenter", function(){
 $('.zagimg').attr('src', $(this).attr('data-back-src'));
});
```

Comment: Normally, SO is not a free code writing or translation service. You have to show at least some effort to solve a problem on your own. If you have actual problems with that add a [mcve] and explain the problems and add any errors.

Comment: Don't be aimlessly scared :') what is your specific concern?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you have a single record:

```
document.querySelector('a.zag').addEventListener('mouseenter', (evt) => {
  document.querySelector('.zagimg').setAttribute('src', evt.currentTarget.dataset.backSrc)
})
```

And in case you have multiple a.zag elements and wanna update multiple .zagimg:

```
document.querySelectorAll('a.zag').forEach((el) => {
  el.addEventListener('mouseenter', (evt) => {
    document.querySelectorAll('.zagimg').forEach((zagImg) => {
      zagImg.setAttribute('src', evt.currentTarget.dataset.backSrc)
    })
  })
})
```